# MS Access Form - something pops up, how can i find out what?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, office-2010

I used Form_timer() for the first time today.
The code itself appears to work fine.

However, what's driving me nuts, is that every time I add a new line of code in that Form, my editor window loses focus, and I see some kind of notification window pop up from the Form (happens in any mode).

That notification vanishes immediately, so i have no idea at all, what it's about, although i think i glimpsed the word error.

Is there a way to prevent that popup from closing, so that I at least have a chance to find out what's going on? If not, is there another way to find out what's going on?

Comment: Does the same happen in Design mode?

Comment: Yes. As i wrote, happens in any mode.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the timer on the form close, just in case?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Besides it's not running when the form is closed, anyway. Also, while i'm in the form's module editor, the form is always automatically opened in development mode. I just tried the effect of setting Timerinterval to 0 in properties - popup still happens.

Comment: Have you shut down the DB and gone back in, just turning the timer off may have left something connected to it somehow....

Comment: Yeah, autorepair on closing it, too.